# ImportError: cannot import name 'voc' from 'data' (unknown location)

Tags: python, anaconda, torch, torchvision

I have been trying to run a code of ssd from the project https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch.git
but the above error keeps on poping up. There is some issue with the directory i guess. Please guide!!

I am trying to import the below files but unable to do it and

```
cannot import name 'BaseTransform' from 'data' (unknown location)
```

this shows up
When I tried to run the ssd python file from the above link then I got

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'voc' from 'data' (unknown location)
```

So basically there is some path issue I guess.

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import cv2
from data import BaseTransform, VOC_CLASSES as labelmap
from ssd import bulid_ssd
import imageio
```

Or please tell me in which directory should I put my project python file and https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch.git files to make the above import statements work when data and ssd are from https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch.git

PS: ssd is Single Shot MultiBox Detector and I am using anaconda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to download the project, and it should have a folder with name data, inside of it, should exists a class with this name.

Example of structure
your_file.py
data
  |_ xxx.py

Example of code of xxx.py

class BaseTransform:
   xxxxxx